# paper-textarea remove scrollbars on IE11

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

just trying to get rid of scrollbars on IE11 when nothing is inputted and have them only when needed i.e. overflow: auto

works on a generice textarea but no on paper

tried

```
--paper-input-container: {
  overflow: auto;
}

paper-textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

but nothing